# running assembly on linux server (putty)

Tags: assembly

For my class I have to run a simple assembly program that I wrote on a linux server using putty. For reference, this is IA32 assembly. I know how to write the "meat" of the code, such as storing and loading to registers, but I don't know how to run this thing. Can anyone help me, or point me to a resource to learn how to do this?

Comment: http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html contains a complete instruction for a hello world sample.

Answer (score 0):

You assemble and link obviously. For some *nix tutorials, see http://int80h.org/ but be warned, most use AT&T syntax.